# Count total number of modal verbs in text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to create a custom collection of words as shown in the following Categories:

```
Modal    Tentative    Certainty    Generalizing
Can      Anyhow       Undoubtedly  Generally
May      anytime      Ofcourse     Overall
Might    anything     Definitely   On the Whole
Must     hazy         No doubt     In general
Shall    hope         Doubtless    All in all
ought to hoped        Never        Basically
will     uncertain    always       Essentially
need     undecidable  absolute     Most
Be to    occasional   assure       Every
Have to  somebody     certain      Some
Would    someone      clear        Often
Should   something    clearly      Rarely
Could    sort         inevitable   None
Used to  sorta        forever      Always
```

I am reading text from a CSV file row by row:

```py
import nltk
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

count = defaultdict(int)
header_list = ["modal","Tentative","Certainity","Generalization"]
categorydf = pd.read_csv('Custom-Dictionary1.csv', names=header_list)
def analyze(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    modals = str(categorydf['modal'])
    tentative = str(categorydf['Tentative'])
    certainity = str(categorydf['Certainity'])
    generalization = str(categorydf['Generalization'])
    for text in df["Text"]:
        tokenize_text = text.split()
        for w in tokenize_text:          
            if w in modals:
                count[w] += 1
                       
analyze("test1.csv")
print(sum(count.values()))
print(count)
```

I want to find number of **Modal/Tentative/Certainty** verbs which are present in the above table and in each row in test1.csv, but not able to do so. This is generating words frequency with number.

```
19
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'to': 7, 'an': 1, 'will': 2, 'a': 7, 'all': 2})
```

See 'an','a' are not present in the table. I want to get **No of Model verbs** = total modal verbs present in 1 row of test.csv text

`test1.csv`:

```
"When LIWC was first developed, the goal was to devise an efficient will system"
"Within a few years, it became clear that there are two very broad categories of words"
"Content words are generally nouns, regular verbs, and many adjectives and adverbs."
"They convey the content of a communication."
"To go back to the phrase “It was a dark and stormy night” the content words are: “dark,” “stormy,” and “night.”"
```

I am stuck and not getting anything. How can I proceed?

Comment: Can you please also provide both tables not only in form of image, but also as plain text in question? So that we can use this data to test our corrected versions of scripts.

Comment: Like "efficient will" illustrates, you need to do context analysis to figure out whether this is a modal verb or a noun. You get similar problems with "can" and (to a lesser extent) "must".

Comment: `str(categorydf['modal'])` is not the correct way to check for string in a `pd.Series`.

Comment: I have pasted the content in Google sheets. Here is the link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15GtfYCI0K4QdaqCmomXxPooPrAlPGd083PKBYFLHrUE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @HenryYik Thanks for pointing out. Since df returns object so i have casted it to string.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the reply. I just need to find the occurrence of these words in text( which would be tweets actually). These numbers would be using in Sentiment analysis. I will definitely look for contextual analysis though.

Comment: No, [edit] the question so everything can be copy/pasted from here without visiting external sites. Google Docs is particularly pesky because it requires you to log in. Your question should be self-contained; comments you add down here will also be prone to disappear, so you will also want to update the question itself with the additional information you have provided here.

Comment: I have added the content as HTML content. I hope it is ok now.@Arty  @tripleee

Comment: Why do you say it's CSV when it's HTML? Why don't you simply attach the CSV file straight?

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR I've created [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116108/941531), my main interest was to make fast solution (although maybe a bit complex) using NumPy.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64116108/941531) I've just added at the end second solution, which is much more simpler than first one, just in few lines, it is slower, but uses pure Python, like you did in your solution, you'll like it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved your task for initial CSV format, could be of cause adopted to XML input if needed.

I've did quite fancy solution using [NumPy](https://numpy.org/), that's why solution might be a bit complex, but runs very fast and suitable for large data, even Giga-Bytes.

It uses sorted table of words, also sorts text to count words and sorted-search in table, hence works in `O(n log n)` time complexity.

It outputs original text line on first line, then Found-line where it lists each found in Tabl word in sorted order with (Count, Modality, (TableRow, TableCol)), then Non-Found-line where it lists non-found-in-table words plus Count (number of occurancies of this word in text).

Also a much simpler (but slower) similar solution is located after the first one.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64114399#main.py)

```
import io, pandas as pd, numpy as np

# Instead of io.StringIO(...) provide filename.
tab = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Modal,Tentative,Certainty,Generalizing
Can,Anyhow,Undoubtedly,Generally
May,anytime,Ofcourse,Overall
Might,anything,Definitely,On the Whole
Must,hazy,No doubt,In general
Shall,hope,Doubtless,All in all
ought to,hoped,Never,Basically
will,uncertain,always,Essentially
need,undecidable,absolute,Most
Be to,occasional,assure,Every
Have to,somebody,certain,Some
Would,someone,clear,Often
Should,something,clearly,Rarely
Could,sort,inevitable,None
Used to,sorta,forever,Always
"""))
tabc = np.array(tab.columns.values.tolist(), dtype = np.str_)
taba = tab.values.astype(np.str_)
tabw = np.char.lower(taba.ravel())
tabi = np.zeros([tabw.size, 2], dtype = np.int64)
tabi[:, 0], tabi[:, 1] = [e.ravel() for e in np.split(np.mgrid[:taba.shape[0], :taba.shape[1]], 2, axis = 0)]
t = np.argsort(tabw)
tabw, tabi = tabw[t], tabi[t, :]

texts = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""
Text
"When LIWC was first developed, the goal was to devise an efficient will system"
"Within a few years, it became clear that there are two very broad categories of words"
"Content words are generally nouns, regular verbs, and many adjectives and adverbs."
They convey the content of a communication.
"To go back to the phrase “It was a dark and stormy night” the content words are: “dark,” “stormy,” and “night.”"
""")).values[:, 0].astype(np.str_)

for i, (a, text) in enumerate(zip(map(np.array, np.char.split(texts)), texts)):
    vs, cs = np.unique(np.char.lower(a), return_counts = True)
    ps = np.searchsorted(tabw, vs)
    unc = np.zeros_like(a, dtype = np.bool_)
    psm = ps < tabi.shape[0]
    psm[psm] = tabw[ps[psm]] == vs[psm]
    print(
        i, ': Text:', text,
        '\nFound:',
        ', '.join([f'"{vs[i]}": ({cs[i]}, {tabc[tabi[ps[i], 1]]}, ({tabi[ps[i], 0]}, {tabi[ps[i], 1]}))'
            for i in np.flatnonzero(psm).tolist()]),
        '\nNon-Found:',
        ', '.join([f'"{vs[i]}": {cs[i]}'
            for i in np.flatnonzero(~psm).tolist()]),
        '\n',
    )
```

Outputs:

```
0 : Text: When LIWC was first developed, the goal was to devise an efficient will system
Found: "will": (1, Modal, (6, 0))
Non-Found: "an": 1, "developed,": 1, "devise": 1, "efficient": 1, "first": 1, "goal": 1, "liwc": 1, "system": 1, "the": 1, "to": 1, "was": 2, "when":
 1

1 : Text: Within a few years, it became clear that there are two very broad categories of words
Found: "clear": (1, Certainty, (10, 2))
Non-Found: "a": 1, "are": 1, "became": 1, "broad": 1, "categories": 1, "few": 1, "it": 1, "of": 1, "that": 1, "there": 1, "two": 1, "very": 1, "withi
n": 1, "words": 1, "years,": 1

2 : Text: Content words are generally nouns, regular verbs, and many adjectives and adverbs.
Found: "generally": (1, Generalizing, (0, 3))
Non-Found: "adjectives": 1, "adverbs.": 1, "and": 2, "are": 1, "content": 1, "many": 1, "nouns,": 1, "regular": 1, "verbs,": 1, "words": 1

3 : Text: They convey the content of a communication.
Found:
Non-Found: "a": 1, "communication.": 1, "content": 1, "convey": 1, "of": 1, "the": 1, "they": 1

4 : Text: To go back to the phrase “It was a dark and stormy night” the content words are: “dark,” “stormy,” and “night.”
Found:
Non-Found: "a": 1, "and": 2, "are:": 1, "back": 1, "content": 1, "dark": 1, "go": 1, "night”": 1, "phrase": 1, "stormy": 1, "the": 2, "to": 2, "was":
 1, "words": 1, "“dark,”": 1, "“it": 1, "“night.”": 1, "“stormy,”": 1
```

Second solution is implemented in pure Python just for simplicity, only standard python modules `io` and `csv` are used.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVRNbxs3EL3zVwzUg1YosUjRm4EcHDtoBVQ2EDvwQRAK7nJWS5tLCuSs1I1hID@k/XP5I@4MZSnpqQIELefjPc6bt9pN1Mfw6@urG3YxEbiooc17pX6CZciExkLsOFrfUXJhu7yt6rpewOOYCZJkuxQH6JzHYAasFZkG3gtCfe1a@sQVmKof22ez2Spa4/U9BjLk9qivMJFxgSb9GwZMxrsvXKuuTNCXYerjQX8ONo4NofXnGj@plZm0CRO5AfVt18YxZX7Yl6xauW1PJd0zmL7GzgVHyAC3AahHeOijR7XiQXRvvkz6JkIh0csA2yOHuusZSvdxh/pach5z1pfegwsgJHFkEqBYSqy@QSbXH0x2bbngwXH3GNrjfNr4g5my/pgzj@5KRUBuG4PF1lnTeNSmydGPhHoVM6kPKOCxbRkyBhbN5Dwm1B@ZZ1K/m33J5zhgE@2kT0R3HFAPcfS25GJA3Xo0iVUiDDzVOXUUpyRZmU8msUDq6i2dSLuAe0flZjcMoz5ntEdKZtJdTGXiyzKY4tUuFkoR/kX5f02gZg89Bvhj@XAFB5PZQoktZRnPFy3LjrbR@JKlKCmXEUwA7DrXOtYQRGDIE/t0EEAn44CBDg8w8UhZgyNosGVrQhmSUQ0JdGIk/tIhgmgJTYps5tYQbmNymMX1h5hsZtyrGKiwybm0bU8ehBDHwDQJt6NneMZq@GiChYG9B8Y@YismzyVmbCmoZ@q@xwnaGPb8I5O2bxxMa/gwDGNgExFvvVaz@8hKQGPaJxFCynd9MizGt69/L6kIZMCa9FRIMsU08M3kBfj29Z//wJ9HuJBeadFSws/HrnISEI4UgJoDs7JZzStCb@U1l@2u5/e85/lGFm4axxHLu67EGGirdbWvfTzw2rnvaQHsFEB5a@T/QQ5PGvZyxppfyiFXiw1b5@ScNZ7Qf2iU3EYpCcjzOXahgD9tIA1DtNz9/KL5W6JSLCOfik93qvPOO6oWx175uO57IY/zPfEGvpbsplAcH8XggeotUiVnDe8W8DP8okv7saRg7NjyVM01zOvH6EK17mbzZ0m/zC@gej5Dy6XP4C@L2fnuGv6UW70JK5xvirGwbJ734M3QWAO8Uly/2xQhX1//BQ)

```
import io, csv

# Instead of io.StringIO(...) just read from filename.
tab = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO("""Modal,Tentative,Certainty,Generalizing
Can,Anyhow,Undoubtedly,Generally
May,anytime,Ofcourse,Overall
Might,anything,Definitely,On the Whole
Must,hazy,No doubt,In general
Shall,hope,Doubtless,All in all
ought to,hoped,Never,Basically
will,uncertain,always,Essentially
need,undecidable,absolute,Most
Be to,occasional,assure,Every
Have to,somebody,certain,Some
Would,someone,clear,Often
Should,something,clearly,Rarely
Could,sort,inevitable,None
Used to,sorta,forever,Always
"""))

texts = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO("""
"When LIWC was first developed, the goal was to devise an efficient will system"
"Within a few years, it became clear that there are two very broad categories of words"
"Content words are generally nouns, regular verbs, and many adjectives and adverbs."
They convey the content of a communication.
"To go back to the phrase “It was a dark and stormy night” the content words are: “dark,” “stormy,” and “night.”"
"""), fieldnames = ['Text'])

tabi = dict(sorted([(v.lower(), k) for e in tab for k, v in e.items()]))
texts = [e['Text'] for e in texts]

for text in texts:
    cnt, mod = {}, {}
    for word in text.lower().split():
        if word in tabi:
            cnt[word], mod[word] = cnt.get(word, 0) + 1, tabi[word]
    print(', '.join([f"'{word}': ({cnt[word]}, {mod[word]})" for word, _ in sorted(cnt.items(), key = lambda e: e[0])]))
```

It outputs:

```
'will': (1, Modal)
'clear': (1, Certainty)
'generally': (1, Generalizing)
```

I'm reading from `StringIO` content of CSV, that is to convenience so that code contains everything without need of extra files, for sure in your case you'll need direct files reading, for this you may do same as in next code and next link (named `Try it online!`):

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64114399var3#main.py)

```
import io, csv

tab = csv.DictReader(open('table.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig'))
texts = csv.DictReader(open('texts.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8-sig'), fieldnames = ['Text'])

tabi = dict(sorted([(v.lower(), k) for e in tab for k, v in e.items()]))
texts = [e['Text'] for e in texts]

for text in texts:
    cnt, mod = {}, {}
    for word in text.lower().split():
        if word in tabi:
            cnt[word], mod[word] = cnt.get(word, 0) + 1, tabi[word]
    print(', '.join([f"'{word}': ({cnt[word]}, {mod[word]})" for word, _ in sorted(cnt.items(), key = lambda e: e[0])]))
```

Comment: Thanks for replying @Arty. I am still trying to understand your code. Can you please check as i am getting Key error :Text in:  texts = [e['Text'] for e in texts] .

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR This is depends on the way how your texts CSV file is organized. If you look at my example CSV right inside my code you'll how my looks like. It has very first line Text which gives the name for text column. `e['Text']` is basically getting value of the cell by column name.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR I've just updated my code in answer to reflect that change. I've removed "Text" from first line and added param to dict reader `fieldnames = ['Text']`. Now it looks like your CSV file. Try it! Now you can run it in your CSV without any change.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR BTW I do expected that instead of putting whole text of CSV into code like I did in example, you might want to put just a file name. I put it into code so that you don't have provide extra files in my example. E.g. you just may have one line `texts = csv.DictReader(open('texts.csv', 'r', encoding = 'utf-8'), fieldnames = ['Text'])`, but instead of `utf-8` encoding here you may put encoding that your file is encoded with, it is usually `utf-8` but sometimes may be `cp1252` or others.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR If you provide me with download link to raw download of your two CSV files (not Excel link like you did, but raw download of CSV as they look like) then I may fix my code in order to exactly match your CSV format.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR Pleas look [here](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64114399var3#main.py) I've changed code to reading from two files. Code became really small! On this link you may see on the left two CSV files provided. Click on them, you'll see the way they look like in my case. That is how I expect them to be.

Comment: @NEERAJKUMAR I've updated my answer, see the very end of answer, there's same code but with files reading, and also a link (named `Try it online!`), open it an you'll see whole Python project with two CSV files attached on the left, you'll need to have these CSVs in same form as I do there.

Comment: Thanks for the support. Above code provides result as shown in [https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow64114399var3#main.py}. Just one last query if Modal  words (will/can) appears more than once in a sentence, code returns (2,Modal) (4,Modal). Can we group this as Modals:6 or if 4 tentative and 2 modal words appears then Tentative:4, Modal:2